# Makefile: Copy using make variables --> error; Not so without variables!

Tags: make, file-copy, gnu, error-handling, variable-substitution

In the following makefile

```
InputLocation:=./Test
OutputLocation:=$(InputLocation)/Output
Input:=$(wildcard $(InputLocation)/*.md)
Output:=$(patsubst $(InputLocation)/%, $(OutputLocation)/%, $(Input:Input=Output))

.PHONY: all
all: $(Output)

$(OutputLocation)/%.md : $(InputLocation)/%.md
    cp -rf $< $@;
    ActualFilePath="$<"
    InterimFile1Path="$@"
    #cp -rf $(ActualFilePath) $(InterimFile1Path);
```

`cp -rf $< $@;` copies file successfully.

While `cp -rf $(ActualFilePath) $(InterimFile1Path)` gives an error `cp: missing file operand`

Why is it so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run `make -n` to see the commands that would be executed, or run `make` without options and look at the commands that are executed. Doing this would probably already answer your question, and if not, it would allow us to know what happens.

From the fragment you show, it seems you want to assign shell variables and later use make variables. So `TargetLocation` seems to be a `make` variable, while `ActualFilePath="$<"` seems to be a command meant for the shell.

Depending on the rest of the file, this may work:

```
ActualFilePath="$<"; \
InterimFile1="tempHTML.md"; \
InterimFile1Path="$(TargetLocation)/$${InterimFile1}" ; \
cp -rf $${ActualFilePath} $${InterimFile1Path};
```

**Edit**

In the indented part of the rules, you are not assigning `make` variables, you specify shell commands.

This should work:

```
$(OutputLocation)/%.md : $(InputLocation)/%.md
    cp -rf $< $@;
    ActualFilePath="$<"; \
    InterimFile1Path="$@"; \
    cp -rf $${ActualFilePath} $${InterimFile1Path}
```

And this should work, too:

```
ActualFilePath="$<"
InterimFile1Path="$@"
$(OutputLocation)/%.md : $(InputLocation)/%.md
    cp -rf $(ActualFilePath) $(InterimFile1Path);
```

Comment: `$(InterimFile1)` is also make variable. I think `$$(InterimFile1)` this will be wrong as `$$(InterimFile1)` gets converted by make to `$(InterimFile1)` and passed to shell. And for shell `$(InterimFile1)` is not correct way of variable substitution.

Comment: Sorry about the typos. Still, if you want help, create a minimal but complete makefile that exposes the problem and include it in the question.